# Wordpress Theme [WP-simple] Scroll issue

Tags: wordpress, scrollbar, nicescroll

I'm working on a website. I used wordpress them WP-Simple

I modified the theme for my needs and everything works fine, except it is not scrolling on sub pages.

http://pranicenergy.55freehost.com/site/ - - Main page works fine.
http://pranicenergy.55freehost.com/site/healing/ - - sub page is not scrolling.

please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a meanwhile i figured out the problem! I made a lot of changes to the theme. I deactivated every plugins and one by one i re-did the changes. Now it's working fine.

And one thing i did to fix the preexisting padding issue while scrolling in the banner div is by calling the clear function in **header.php** after **get_template_part( 'parts/header','banner');**

Please use this if you have the same problem.

```
get_template_part( 'parts/header','banner');
nimbus_clear();
```